# Does MySQL server implicitly support encoding conversion?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I need to implement a sorted `SELECT`, on a specific encoding of a field, **without** `CONVERT`.

That is, normally I'd do it by

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CONVERT(field USING gbk) COLLATE gbk_chinese_ci
```

However for some reason `CONVERT` was not allowed. As a result, I tried to approach this by

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY field VARCHAR(xx) CHARACTER SET gbk COLLATE gbk_chinese_ci;

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field
```

It works. That's good. However I'm worried about encoding problems.

Connection to the MySQL server includes the parameters `characterEncoding=utf8` and `useUnicode=true`. I couldn't yet find the explanation of these params in MySQL's official document, but I suppose these ensure that the communications between the client and the server should be in utf-8.

That brings the question. **Does MySQL server implicitly convert data in utf-8 to gbk when it receives the data? Do the GET params only define the charset of communication rather than that of the final stored data?**

---

***Edit***

Comments say that the server does convert them! Thanks guys!

My further confusion is that, only one of the fields is set to use `gbk`, while everything else has been left to use `utf8`. That means the server's charset should still be `utf8` globally but `gbk` locally for that field only.

Suppose now I fire this line of script to the server

```
INSERT INTO table (field_gbk, field_utf8) VALUES ("a", "b");
```

Does the server:

1. Receive the whole statement in `utf8`;
2. Convert **only** "a" to `gbk` and stores it; and
3. Stores "b" as-is to the database?

Many thanks guys!

Comment: Yes, the client can specify what encoding it'll send text in to the database, and what encoding it'd like in return, and MySQL is aware of the encoding of all text stored in all columns, and it'll do the necessary conversions between all that as needed.

Comment: @deceze Thanks heaps! but do you have any official reference to this bit of functionality?

Comment: *Does MySQL server implicitly convert data in utf-8 to gbk when it receives the data?* Yes, the convertion is performed implicitly according to `character_set_server`, `character_set_client` and `character_set_connection` session settings.

Comment: @Akina - That handles the client's encoding.  The column's charset handles the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

- You specify the encoding of in the client when you connect.
- You specify the encoding ("Character set") of the column you are Inserting into.

MySQL converts from one encoding to the other as it `INSERTs` the rows.  Similarly, it converts the other way when `SELECTing`.

The `CONVERT` function should not (normally) be used for anything.

You are using Java?  `characterEncoding=utf8 and useUnicode=true` is what it uses for declaring the client side.

"gbk" for a single column?  Find.  That column will handled differently than other columns.